# JBoss 7 as deploys automatically

Tags: jboss

I put my jboss on the linux server, exported the war file and placed it on the deployments folder and it automatically deployed. I didn't even had to do it via command line. How is this working?

My jboss has ssl to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Application Deployment documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Application+deployment):

> The standalone/deployments directory in the JBoss Application Server 7 distribution is the location end users can place their deployment content (e.g. war, ear, jar, sar files) to have it automically deployed into the server runtime.

So, if you put a war file in `standalone/deployments`, JBoss will detect it and act as if you had manually deployed it. The documentation page has a lot more info about configuration if you want to change the defaults.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL - I found a better page. The JBoss documentation is surprisingly hard to search through :\

Comment: Yes, it is. I've consistently found the JBoss documentation, at least for Community (read: free) edition, to be very frustrating.